# Missing remote branches in git log for bare repositories

Tags: git, git-bare

When cloning a repositoy with `--bare` `git log` has no status about the remote branches. There might be a good reason for it but I don't get it. `git fetch origin` seems to be successful but the remote branches are still mising in the log.

EDIT: I mean I can add `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` to the `[remote "origin"]` section in the configuration (`git config --edit`) but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1):

Bare repositories do not normally have remote-tracking names (such as `origin/master`) for the same reason they do not have a work-tree: you're not supposed to do any work in them.

Remote-tracking names are useful for doing work.  They let you compare your current branch to its upstream, when its upstream is set to the corresponding remote-tracking branch.  But for that to be useful, you'd have to `git checkout` some branch locally, to create it, and then do some work.  With no work-tree, you can't do that.  So that's not useful after all, so there's no need for a remote-tracking name either.

If you *do* have some weird scenario in which you really *do* want remote-tracking names in a bare clone in which you do no work, just add the `fetch` line you mentioned in your edit.